# Align tcbox which has a boxed title at bottom with line text

Tags: vertical-alignment, tcolorbox, alignment

If I compile:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\tcbset{colframe=red!50!white,nobeforeafter}
Some text\dots
\tcbox[nobeforeafter,box align=base, attach boxed title to bottom,title=AA,enhanced]{One line$\frac{x}{y}$}\tcbox[nobeforeafter,box align=base,size=fbox]{Another line}
\end{document}
```

I get (annotation added by me)

[image]

I know I can use the `baseline` key to change the alignment of the box with title at bottom. But how can this be done automatically?